# MathNet.Numerics Determinant Solve Accuracy

Tags: c#, math, matrix, determinants

There is a code that solve the determinant of N*N matrix.

```
Matrix<double> m = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(8, 8);
Console.WriteLine(m.Determinant());
```

For example, I get answer 1,028123616921736E+29.
But I need pure accuracy to get 102812361692173611981120593161.
Is there a way to solve that problem?

Comment: AFAIK, Mathnet only does not support numbers with more precsion than double. But you can do your own determinant implementation based on decimal quite easily.

Comment: How? Could you please explain

Comment: Most easily using the Leibniz rule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant). Note this is very inefficient, but you don't state your performance requirements.

Comment: @KlausGütter [`Decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-6.0) only goes up to `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` which is less than the OP's required `102,812,361,692,173,611,981,120,593,161`

Comment: @MatthewWatson good catch. So perhaps [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) - if the matrix elements are integer.